# Proving that sequence is always irrational

Tags: real-analysis

I have a recursive sequence $(x_n)$ where $x_1= \sqrt{2}$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+x_n}$.

Comment: The well ordered principle is a way of doing induction backwards and this works nicely by contradiction.  $x_1$ is irrational so if *any* $x_n$ rational there must be a *first* rational term.  So let $x_k$ be the *first* term that is rational.  So $x_k = \sqrt{2 + x_{k-1}}$ is rational but $x_{k-1}$ is irrational.  It's easy to show that is a contradiction ($x_k^2 -2 = x_{k-1}$.  LHS is rational but RHS is not).  SO there can't be any first term that is rational.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn the recurrence around to $x_n = x_{n+1}^2 - 2$.  Thus if $x_{n+1}$ is rational, so is $x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is rational, $r^2$ is rational. Now use induction.

Answer (score 0):

Do an induction proof where the induction step is a proof by contradiction.

Base step: $x_1$ is irrational (obvious).

Induction step: Assume $x_k$ is irrational.  Prove $x_{k+1}$ is irrational by a proof by contradiction.

Pf:  Assume $x_{k+1} = \sqrt{2 +x_k}$ is rational. While $x_k$ is irrational.

Then $x_{k+1}^2 = 2 + x_k$ is rational.  So $x_k$ is rational. A contradiction.

So $x_k$ is irrational $\implies x_{k+1}$ is irrational.

....

So induction step is done.

So we just did a proof by induction for all $x_n$.